# Create android html5 game development

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to learn Android game development with html5 and JavaScript. I created the android apps using ionic framework. Is there is any framework for game development like ionic framework?

Comment: End Engine is good framework for Android game development.

Comment: I believe AndEngine is not a javascript game framework

Comment: Yes You are right @ Emre

Answer (score 2):

The following Framework are support the HTML5 based game development

1. Phaser (http://phaser.io/)
2. createjs (http://createjs.com/)
3. pixijs (https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js)
4. threejs (http://threejs.org/)
5. playcanvas (https://playcanvas.com/)
6. turbulenz (http://biz.turbulenz.com/developers)
7. lycheejs (http://lycheejs.org/index.html)

More details [Etc](https://html5gameengine.com/)